# Does each monotonic endofunctor on the category of sets and relations preserve conversion?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, functoriality

Consider a functor $F : \mathbf{Rel} \to \mathbf{Rel}$ that is monotonic (for all relations $R$ and $S$ with $R \subseteq S$ we have $FR \subseteq FS$). Does such a functor always preserve conversion of relations, that is, does $F\bigl(R^{-1}\bigr) = (FR)^{-1}$ always hold? I cannot see how this property should follow from the functor axioms and the monotonicity property, but I cannot come up with an example where it doesn’t hold. Is the situation different when $F$ is not just a functor but a monad?

Comment: You're asking for a **relator**: a functor that is monotonic and respects converse. See for example https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a458/a4088f7f1963f0036307b35aa7239ab71a34.pdf or other works of Roland Backhouse.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In fact, my question could be rephrased as “Is every monotonic endofunctor on $\mathbf{Rel}$ a relator?”. The fact that the authors explicitly require preservation of conversion suggests that this property does not follow from the other ones. However, it would be great to have an example of a monotonic endofunctor on $\mathbf{Rel}$ that is not a relator (that is, doesn’t preserve conversion).

Comment: **Rel** is logically complete for the theory of [tabular?] allegories, afaik. That is to say, anything provable in **Rel** holds for all other [tabular?] allegories. Hence if preservation of conversion did hold in *Rel*, then it would hold in all other allegories rendering the definition of *relator* to have redundant requirements. Consider taking a look at the classic *Categories, Allegories* text or the definitions of *relator* in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.9107&rep=rep1&type=pdf might be helpful..